# Group by two or more entries into single record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I am struggling to come up with an elegant way to do this grouping. Here is some example data… 
I can’t come up with something (that’s not completely convoluted)

```
Create table tax(Prod_ID varchar(15), Authority varchar(15), Rate     decimal(15,10)) 
insert into tax(prod_id, Authority, rate) 
VALUES
('UNL',       'TX',  0.20000000000000000000000), 
('UNL',       'USA', 0.18300000000000000000000), 
('UNL',       'USA', 0.00100000000000000000000), 
('UNL',       'TX',  0.00099285714285714285714), 
('UNL',       'AL',  0.18000000000000000000000)
```

Any entry with an 'Authority' of 'USA' will need to be added to EVERY 'Authority' that is a state, e.g., TX, AL, FL, etc. 
So what I’d like to end up with from the above data is as follows…

```
Prod_ID, Authority, Sum(Rate)
UNL, TX, 0.38499285714285714285714
UNL, AL, 0.36400000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
select t.prod_id 'Prod_ID', t.authority 'Authority',
        (SUM(Rate) +(SELECT SUM(RATE) FROM tax t where Authority = 'USA'))  as 'Sum(Rate)'
from tax t 
WHERE Authority <> 'USA'
GROUP BY Prod_ID,Authority
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think a `JOIN` is sufficient:

```
with t as (
      select t.prod_id, t.authority, sum(t.rate) as rate
      from tax t
      group by t.prod_id, t.authority
     )   
select t.prod_id, t.authority,
       (t.rate + coalesce(tusa.rate, 0)) as total_rate
from t left join
     t tusa
     on t.prod_id = tusa.prod_id and tusa.authority = 'USA'
where t.authority <> 'USA'
```

Comment: You may be on to something, but it looks like it's double counting the 'USA' entries when I group it.   The query above returns...
<!-- language-all: sql -->
> UNL, TX, 0.3830000000
> UNL, TX, 0.2010000000
> UNL, TX, 0.1839928571
> UNL, TX, 0.0019928571
> UNL, AL, 0.3630000000
> UNL, AL, 0.1810000000

which groups to... 
> UNL, AL, 0.5440000000
> UNL, TX, 0.7699857142

Comment: @Ralph . . . Everything needs to be aggregated first.  You have multiple rows for each authority, but want only one in the result set.